# Using output from a substring (xstring) conditional within a url (href)

Tags: xstring, href

Unable to pass output from a substring conditional into a URL:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\substring}{%
  \IfSubStr{%
  Physics,%
  Chemistry,%
  Biology,%
  }{Physics}{https://www.google.com}{}%
}%

\begin{document}

\url{\substring}

\end{document}
```

Output:

- Error: Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa. [\url{\substring}]

Intended output:

- https://www.google.com

What is the best way to achieve the intended output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not expandable. You could change the command to define a macro appropriately, or build the `\href` command in your macro.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\substring}{%
  \IfSubStr{%
  Physics,%
  Chemistry,%
  Biology,%
  }{Physics}{\def\MyUrl{https://www.google.com}}{\def\MyUrl{}}%
}%


\newcommand{\ConditionalURL}[1]{%
  \IfSubStr{%
  Physics,%
  Chemistry,%
  Biology,%
  }{#1}{\url{https://www.google.com}}{}%
}%

\begin{document}
\substring\url{\MyUrl}

\ConditionalURL{Physics}
\end{document}
```